# Android WebView onPageFinished BUG

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After update API (27) in Android OREO this code is no longer working:

```
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     super.onPageFinished(view, url);
     view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.getElementById(\"imPage\").style.display='none';})()");
 }
```

I have also tried with:

```
webView.loadUrl(
                    "javascript:(function() { " +

                            "document.addEventListener(\"DOMContentLoaded\", function(event) {" +

                            "document.getElementById(\"imPage\").style.display='none';" +

                            "});" +

                            "})()");
```

Element not hiding and debug return:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null", source: mywebsite/ (1)
```

So I think the `javascript` is injected before loading page, this explains why the line is 1, because I have other code called after loading page is finished but this code is called when page is white, not loaded.

Comment: can you log what url is passed to onPageFinished on OREO and on older systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my own project I have been using `evaluateJavascript(script,null)` in onPageFinished to hide html elements. `view.loadUrl()` Should work the same way.

If you don't need the function be called at later time you could simplify your JS string and instead of `\"` try using `'`.

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
super.onPageFinished(view, url);
view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('imPage').style.display='none';");}
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById(\"imPage\")` must be returning `null`.

So there is either no `imPage`element or you haven't loaded the page at the time.

I would suggest moving your entire js code into

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //insert here
});
```

Comment: Try to remove the "\" from getElementById(\"imPage\") then, maybe that is why it returns null

Answer (score -2):

You have to enable Javascript Seetings like below :-

```
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //Yes you have to do it
```

Comment: Yes i have enabled =)